# local storage best score is undefined/no value

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

```
if (typeof localStorage["BestScore"] === 'undefined') {
    localStorage["BestScore"] = 0;
    var maxScore=0;
}     
else {
    var maxScore= localStorage["BestScore"] 
}
```

This code tries to check if the local storage best score is `undefined/no value` and if it is it sets maxscore to `0` if it has a value it set maxscore to the value. For some reason this code is not working please help.

Comment: Seems to be working fine. What is the problem? Does the browser support localStorage?

Comment: What do you get if you execute localStorage["BestScore"] in the JS console.

Comment: Im sure it supports local storage. And in the js console it said undefined.

Comment: This is what happens when i run it when i have the maxscore = the local storage http://imageshack.com/a/img691/167/28x1.png and it is frozen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what i use. first check that storage is possible then check that your object is there. so...

```
if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {
    if (!localStorage.BestScore) {
        localStorage.BestScore = 0;
    }

    var maxScore = localStorage.BestScore; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You missed a ; on line 6.

```
if (typeof localStorage["BestScore"] === 'undefined') {
  localStorage["BestScore"] = 0;
  var maxScore=0;
}else {
  var maxScore= localStorage["BestScore"] ;
}
```

Comment: `;` is _optional_ in JavaScript as long as you only have one expression per line.

Comment: This is a very very bad practice, though.

Comment: That might be … but that still not makes it an _answer_ to the question asked here.